# Difference and relation between ed25519, x25519 and XEd25519

Tags: public-key, elliptic-curves, dsa, ed25519, x25519

In my Rust implementation of a messaging system, I'm using currently two cryptographic primitives: *ed25519_dalek* and *x25519_dalek*. I use *ed25519_dalek* for DSA, while *x25519_dalek* for encryption of the message since I need to do a Diffie-Hellman key exchange. I wonder whether I could use the same primitive for both DSA and DH, and if not why? Also, some time ago Signal described the XEd25519 signature schema https://signal.org/docs/specifications/xeddsa/ which they say *"XEdDSA enables the use of a single key pair format for both elliptic curve Diffie-Hellman and signatures"*. What is the relation between those primitives, can I for example convert *ed25519_dalek* and *x25519_dalek* keys into XEd25519?

Comment: also, related [Why Curve25519 for encryption but Ed25519 for signatures?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/27866/18298)

Comment: Yes, thank you!